# SQL CLR how to access username, hostname, and app_name running in safe mode

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2005, sqlclr

I have a trigger written in sql clr (sql 2005, .net 3.5) and I need to get at username, hostname and app_name.  In TSQL I would simply use

```
select suser_name()
select host_name()
select APP_NAME()
```

In my .Net code I tried

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name
System.Environment.MachineName
System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ApplicationIdentity.FullName
```

but running in safe mode I do not have access to any of these properties.  Any ideas on how to acomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [context connection](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005#p5) and execute the necessary TSQL to retrieve the values you need.

In your CLR trigger definition:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = "Context Connection=true";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = conn;

cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT suser_name() as suser_name, host_name() as host_name, APP_NAME() as app_name";

conn.Open();
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: @ED yes I thought of that but I then need to use those values in a stored procedure call. I'm trying to minimize my calls through context connection.  This is a definite possibility though and what I may have to end up doing.